# Debugging output

Tags: mysql, sed, gnu-parallel

I attempted to speed up an import of a large dataset with a folder full of .sql files

```
ls -rS *.sql | parallel -j16 mysql -uusername -ppassword dbname "<"
```

Shortly after running this I get an error:

```
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 65: Table 'dbname.some_table' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 69: Table 'dbname.some_table_other' doesn't exist
```

Is there a simple way to modify this command line arg to find out which file is generating this error?

I've tried doing a script that runs a sed on line 65-69 of all of the files, but there are too many results to know.  Once I determine which sql generated the error I can drop it and re-import it.

Solved: used

```
ls -rS *.sql | xargs grep -i "dbname.some_table" | less
```

to trace back where it was called too early

Comment: Do a simple `grep` on your web directory looking for `dbname.some_table`.

Comment: It is in a ton of files unfortunately..and the files are many gigs in size.  (which is why I attempted to use a sed script on just the specific lines of the files)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running this command in your web data directory:

```
find . -name "*.php" -print | xargs grep -i "dbname.some_table"
```

This will recursively scan all sub directories and loof for files only with the `.php` extension, and then print out any lines that contain the text specified in `grep`.

Comment: It does show the files, but the first result is the result that would create the table itself - not the file that is referencing it that is generating the error. (I replaced the "*.php" with "*.sql" fyi)

Comment: Edited my answer. Try adding the `-i` switch, and finding any file where this occurs on line `65` or `69`. Also, make sure you check your spelling, small case errors are large errors. If this does not work for you, I apologize, this is all I have for suggestions :[

Comment: Would you happen to know if instead of 'find', there is a way to get it to process in the same order that 'ls -rS *.sql' is generating?  I think if I could do that, I'd be able to find where it is referenced.

Comment: ah I just replaced it..and think I found it used: ls -rS *.sql | xargs grep -i "dbname.some_table" | less

Answer (score 0):

Use --tag:

```
ls -rS *.sql | parallel --tag -j16 sql mysql://username:password@/dbname "<"
```